# PFQueryTableView isn't up-to-date with Parse-data (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2

I'm new to this forum, and – more importantly – I'm also new to the Swift (2) language – and actually in coding at all.

So at the moment I'm trying to work with Parse in Xcode 7 (Swift 2). To be more specific: I'm working with a PFQueryTableView to display the data, I set up in the Parse class, in the app. But my problem is that when I update this data on the Parse website and I run the app in the simulator, the tableview with data isn't up-to-date with my new data from the Parse-website.

After going through other topic-related posts, this is the code I came up with:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "myClass")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Successfully retrieved: \(objects)")
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Now, when I run the app I can see the right data in the Target Output, but in the simulator it's still the old data. So I guess there must be a line of code in the "if error == nil { }"-section. I already tried several lines of codes which I got from other threads, but they all didn't work. And like I said before: I'm still a beginner in coding, so I just can't figure out myself how to do this.

Hopefully one of you guys can help me out. And if I need to be more specific or something, just ask!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you displaying the data?  In a tableview?  If so you need to call `reloadData()` on the tableview once the data has been retrieved

Comment: Yes, the data is being displayed in a tableview, but when I add self.tableView.reloadData() in the "if error==nil { }"-section, the data in the tableview still isn't up to date...

Comment: oh!  also you need to update the array that holds your table data with the `objects` array from the query.

Comment: Oh wow, I'm feeling like a complete fool now, but how do I update that array?

Comment: Basically, assign `objects` to it.  you need to show more code, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would be good